# How to selectively load css in rhtml?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are several pages generated from a same layout.rhtml. Besides a global css file, each page also has its own css file, say page1.css, page2.css corresponding to page1.rhtml, page2.rhtml. Is there any way to seletively load the css files in rhtml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to use .html.erb files. rhtml is really old and I dont think it is supported in Rails 3 and 4 (I can be wrong with this)

Comment: Do you want to load `page1.css` dynamically when `page1` and `page2.css` when `page2` actions are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a instance variable in controller for which css to load. lets say we will use stylefile variable in controller like this:

```
@stylefile = "page1.css"
```

Now write following code where you load css file.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag @stylefile %>
```

Similarly change filename in controller for page2.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly,you can just `include` them with `stylesheet_link_tag` like this

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'page1' %>`

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'page2' %>`

in the .`rhtml` files.